# Socket.io poort 3000

Tags: sockets

Ik heb een webshop en mijn probleem is dat ik een ssl sleutel heb laten installeren maar kom nu tot de conclusie dat mijn tijdscounter niet meer loopt zoals het moet.
Als ik op inspecteren klik krijg ik deze melding : Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.siks123soldshop.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://185.27.141.230:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1489056031089-7'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix HTTP and HTTPS content with AJAX calls, you need to implement https on 185.27.141.230:3000 or find out if the same service is available as https over a different port number.

Comment: Wat kan ik doen om dit op te lossen?